# How Unity determine which scripts will be assembled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Will Unity3D assemble those scripts used in the scene only in the build or all the scripts? If only those in the scene, what about the scripts in the assetbundle?

Answer (score 1):

> The building process (...) will work through the scene list in the build settings, open
>   them in the editor one at a time, optimize them, and integrate them
>   into the application package. It will also calculate all the assets
>   that are required by the included scenes and store that data in a
>   separate file within the application package.

(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html)

According to the quote above, it should only include the scripts you somehow link from a scene.
To be 100% sure, you could load a class not included from a scene using reflection.

Comment: What about asset bundles? They are not in the scene, but scripts inside are pre-compiled.